# Why is my SSD performance much slower than benchmarks for the same device?

Tags: ssd

Vertex 3 drives tend to benchmark much higher and my number are almost indicative of a SATA2 setup but as you can see from the info, I am in SATA 3.

Any ideas of what could be misconfigured?

[image: Crystal Benchmark]

Answer (score 3):

Check that:

1. Drive firmware is the very latest.
2. That the SATA cable itself isn't old/damaged
3. Alternate bench marking software [AS SSD](http://www.overclock.net/t/754763/as-ssd-benchmark-thread) is popular too.
4. That the SSD diagnostic information reports 'healthy' try the [SSDLife](http://ssd-life.com/) app.

Also interference may be an issue, processes running in background, i.e.

1. Indexing service keeping the drive/OS busy
2. Backup software